# In Jenkins, how can I disable "Discard old builds" option via pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, groovy

I have several jobs where I want to disable the option shown below in the jobs' configuration page. How can I do it via pipeline?

[image: Jenkins job config page]

Answer (score 1):

We can't do it by freestyle or manually but we can achieve this by writing a pipeline script for all the jobs in one and running it.

***Example code***:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Disable discard old builds on all jobs') {
      steps {
        // Get all jobs
        def jobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class)

        // Iterate over all jobs and disable the "Discard old builds" option
        jobs.each { job ->
          // Get the job configuration
          def jobConfig = job.getConfigFile()

          // Disable the "Discard old builds" option
          jobConfig.properties.remove(jobConfig.properties.find { it instanceof BuildDiscarderProperty })

          // Update the job configuration
          jobConfig.save()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mention all the jobs accordingly...
& The pipeline job will iterate over all jobs in Jenkins and disable the "Discard old builds" option on each job.

Comment: Almost. I get the error `somePath/someJob
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.XmlFile.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), isCase(java.lang.Object)`

Comment: If I change `jobConfig.save()` to `job.save()` I don't get the error, but I don't see the configuration change.

Comment: I posted the question here also, and someone posted a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77411857/in-jenkins-how-can-i-disable-a-jobs-discard-old-builds-via-pipeline-code/77415259#77415259